# How do you write the ionization equation for calcium hydroxide?

Tags: aqueous-solution, stoichiometry, ionic-compounds

This is a base that would ionize completely, and the dissociation equation would look like this: $$\ce{Ca(OH)2 <--> Ca^2+ + 2OH-}$$ but how would I write the Brønsted equation with water? $$\ce{Ca(OH)2 + H2O -> ?}$$

I know that water auto-ionizes to make $\ce{H3O+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$.

Comment: Rather Lewis, then Bronsted. Cation coordinates water molecules (probably 6 directly).

Comment: Neither the $\ce{H^+}$ ion nor the $\ce{OH^-}$ ion float around in water as the bare ions. Both are "understood" to be in some sort of coordination complex with water molecules. In fact there are probably several layers of water molecules around the ion which are not oriented randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t. You’re done after$$\ce{Ca(OH)2 (s) ->[H2O] Ca^2+ (aq) + 2 OH- (aq)}\tag{1}$$

You may want to write an equation corresponding to the hydroxide version of the [Grotthuss mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grotthuss_mechanism), in which case you might add:
$$\ce{OH- + H2O -> OH2 + HO-}\tag{2}$$
or some permutation of that. But unless you isotopically mark one water molecule or you pinpoint one in solution, this equation does not correspond to a measurable process since reactants and products are identical.